# Razor pages modified object property is empty during rendering

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

This is my example of `idenx.cshtml.cs`

```cs
public IEnumerable<Payment> Entities { get; set; } = default!;

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Entities = (await _paymentService.GetAll())
        .Select(x => new Payment()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            CategoryName = "FOO"
        });
}
```

Everything works, but I changed this code to this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Payment> Entities { get; set; } = default!;

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    
    Entities = await _paymentService.GetAll();
    
    foreach (var entity in Entities)
    {
        entity.CategoryName = "Bar";
    }
}
```

and now, `entity.CategoryName` is always empty during rendering. Why? I noticed this error when debugging razor pages:
[image]

I don't really see what is wrong there, why would I not be able to modify objects parameters value before the rendering?

## edit

I even tried suggestion by @JHBonarius, but still, after exiting `foreach`, the property's value magically dissapear:
[image]

Comment: We need a [mcve]. The new problem tou show is not with blazor.

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor, when you assign to a property like `Entities`, you do not only change the value in the hidden field behind the auto property, but you also trigger an event that signals Blazor to update the page.

In your second piece of code you do update the child properties, but that way this same event is not triggered.

The error that you get is that the inner property was not yet assigned when the update event was triggered.

There are multiple ways to overcome this, but the easiest would be to assign the value to a local variable first and assign the final value to `Enities` at the end of the method.

#Edit:

Regarding your new issue, weigh is separate from the first: `GetAll` seems to return a `SelectlistIterator`. What happens, is that every time you enumerate it, new elements get generated... So the elements generated in the foreach loop only exist within that loop! Each next enumeration after that new elements will get generated.

Solution: add a `.ToArray()` after the `GetAll` to get a fixed array of elements.
Or better: have the payment service return a proper array in the first place.

Comment: It is so frustrating, I updated the question and I still cant make it work

Comment: @dafie set my update